# openCL on Intel HD Graphics 4000 & Nvidia GeForce GT 650M not working: CL_INVALID_DEVICE error

Tags: xcode, macos, opencl, gpu, cpu

so I'm having some issues getting my code to run on certain openCL devices. I'm developing on a mid-2013 15" retina screen Macbook pro on OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and using Xcode 6.0.1

After using clGetDeviceIDs to access all available devices and using clGetDeviceInfo to see the info for each device I get the following:

```
Device: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3635QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
Hardware version: OpenCL 1.2 
Software version: 1.1
OpenCL C version: OpenCL C 1.2 
Parallel compute units: 8

Device: HD Graphics 4000
Hardware version: OpenCL 1.2 
Software version: 1.2(Aug 17 2014 20:29:07)
OpenCL C version: OpenCL C 1.2 
Parallel compute units: 16

Device: GeForce GT 650M
Hardware version: OpenCL 1.2 
Software version: 8.26.28 310.40.55b01
OpenCL C version: OpenCL C 1.2 
Parallel compute units: 2
```

So according to this, I should have 1 CPU and 2 GPUs available: a HD Graphics 4000 and a GeForce GT 650M.

My issue is when I try to call clGetkernelWorkGroupInfo, it returns a CL_INVALID_DEVICE error if I pass in the deviceID of one of the two GPUs but works perfectly fine if I pass in the CPU id and will compute my kernel code without issue.

This is weird because all of my other calls up until that point work for all 3 devices. I can create a context that encompasses all 3 devices, create 3 separate command queues (one per device), and I can compile a program and create the kernel just fine. But as soon as I get to that call it says my device is invalid.

If instead I comment out that call to clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo and specify my own global/local work sizes I get an error when I try to call clEnqueueNDRangeKernel with a CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE error.

Is there something wrong with the graphics cards I have installed on my computer? Or is there something codewise I have to do that I'm not aware of? I just don't see how a device can be valid up until that one call and then suddenly not be valid.

**EDIT** Here is my code (CheckError is just a function I made that prints out a custom error message if there is an error)

```
cl_int err; //Error catcher
cl_platform_id platform; //Computer platform
cl_context context; //Single context for whole platform
cl_uint deviceCount; //Number of devices (CPU + GPU) available on machine
cl_device_id *devices; //Array of pointers to devices;
cl_program program; //OpenCL program
cl_command_queue *commandQueues; //One command queue for each device

/*---Definitions---*/
int DATA_SIZE = 16384;
double results[DATA_SIZE];    //  results returned from device;
int currDevice = 0;           //Use this to just access first available device

/*---Get First Platform---*/
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
CheckError(err, "A valid platform could not be found on this machine");

/*---Get Device Count---*/
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &deviceCount);
CheckError(err, "Could not determine the number of devices available on this platform");

/*---Get All Devices---*/
devices = new cl_device_id[deviceCount];
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, deviceCount, devices, NULL);
CheckError(err, "Could not access the devices");

/*---Create a single context for all devices---*/
context = clCreateContext(NULL, deviceCount, devices, NULL, NULL, &err);
CheckError(err, "Could not create a context on this platform");

/*---For each device create a separate command queue---*/
commandQueues = new cl_command_queue[deviceCount];
for(int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
{
    commandQueues[i] = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[i], 0, &err);
    string errMsg = "Was unable to successfully set up a command queue for device number " + to_string(i);
    CheckError(err, errMsg);
}


/*---Read in cl file---*/
char *KernelSource = ReadFile("./Source/Sampling/Sampler.cl");

//  Create the compute program from the source buffer
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) & KernelSource, NULL, &err);
CheckError(err, "Failed to create compute program!");

//   Build the program executable
err = clBuildProgram(program, deviceCount, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    size_t len;
    char buffer[2048];

    printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[currDevice], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    exit(1);
}

//  Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "mySampler", &err);
CheckError(err, "Failed to create compute kernel!");

// Create the input array in device memory for our calculation
cl_mem input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(double) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, &err);
CheckError(err, "Failed to allocate device memory");

//   Set the arguments to our compute kernel
err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
CheckError(err, "Failed to set kernel arguments");

size_t global, local;

//   Get the maximum work group size for executing the kernel on the device
err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, devices[currDevice], CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);
CheckError(err, "Failed to retrieve work group info!");

//   Execute the kernel over the entire range of our 1d input data set
//   using the maximum number of work group items for this device
global = DATA_SIZE;
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueues[currDevice], kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
CheckError(err, "Failed to execute kernel!");

//  Wait for the command commands to get serviced before reading back results
clFinish(commandQueues[currDevice]);

//  Read back the results from the device to verify the output
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueues[currDevice], input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(double) * DATA_SIZE, results, 0, NULL, NULL );
CheckError(err, "Failed to read array");

std::cout<<"DONE!"<<std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++)
{
    std::cout<<"RESULT: "<<i<<" "<<results[i]<<std::endl;
}

//  Shutdown and cleanup
clReleaseMemObject(input);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueues[currDevice]);
clReleaseContext(context);
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you've built the kernel for the CPU and are then trying to use it on the GPU. Can you show us the host code where you select the platforms, build the program and then perform these queries?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my post in just a sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the program is failing to build for one or both of your GPUs. I've just checked this out on my own OS X system, and `clBuildProgram()` returns `CL_SUCCESS` if it was able to build the program for *any* of the devices you pass it, even if the build fails for the other devices.

If you add this code after the `clBuildProgram()` call you can check if the build actually succeeded for everything:

```
for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
{
  cl_build_status status;
  clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[i], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS,
                        sizeof(status), &status, NULL);
  std::cout << "Build status for device " << i << " = " << status << std::endl;
}
```

I notice you're using `double` values - the HD 4000 does not support double precision and kernels using the `double` type will fail to build. When compiling a kernel that uses `double` with your host code (and the above code snippet), I get the following output:

```
Build status for device 0 = 0
Build status for device 1 = -2
Build status for device 2 = 0
```

As you can see, the build is succeeding for two devices, but not for device 1 (which is the HD 4000).

So, it looks like you need to be careful when building a program for multiple devices at once on Apple systems.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me figure it out. It turns out you were correct, there was some kernel code of mine involving doubles that was screwing up the program build. I thought though that I could get around the double issue by adding: "#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable" to my kernel files, but I guess not